# Unable to stop a recursion even after breaking out of a loop

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem which says to print the sum between two numbers. The function takes three parameters

**start_num: the starting number, end_num: the ending number** and **step: the steps to be jumped.**

```
count = 0
def sequence_sum(start_num, end_number, step):
    global count
    if start_num > end_number:
        return 0

    for i in range(start_num, end_number + 1, step):
        if start_num >= end_number:
            break
        count += i+step
        sequence_sum(i + step, end_number, step)

    return (count)

sequence_sum(1, 5, 1)
```

if the *start_num > end_num* then return 0

Examples:

**sequence_sum(1, 5, 1)  # should give 15. 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15**

**sequence_sum(3, 2, 1) # should return 0**

**sequence_sum(2, 9, 2) # should give 20. 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20**

Comment: Why are you doing a loop AND recursion? Do one or the other. Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this recursively, but iteratively:

```
def sequence_sum(start_num, end_number, step):
    out = 0
    for x in range(start_num, end_number +1, step):
        out += x
    return out
```

or as a oneliner:

```
def sequence_sum(start_num, end_number, step):
    return sum([x for x in range(start_num, end_number +1, step)])
```

or as a labda function:

```
sequence_sum = lambda start_num, end_number, step: sum([x for x in range(start_num, end_number +1, step)])
```